# infinite slider components just loop once then stops

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to implement an infinite slider which should loop forever with no need for buttons to move to the next or the previous, instead, the user can move or pause the slider using touch (this part is not implemented yet, so it's not in the code snippet)

the problem is that I can't get my hands on the logic of the infinite slider, it starts with the last slide (in my case it has the number 5) then gos to 2 => 3 => 4 => 5 => 1 then stops. also, I don't know why it ignores the condition which checks `currentSlide`'s value

```
const allSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".testimonials-tp__review-slider__slide");
const numOfSlides = allSlides.length ;

let currentSlide = 0;

const slider = () => {

    // // Setting each slide's initial position:
    // setToInitialPosition();

     // Moving to the next slide after 2s:
    setInterval(sliding, 2000);
}

const sliding = () => {
    // Reset to the first slide for an infinite loop:
    if(currentSlide === 0 || currentSlide === numOfSlides) setToInitialPosition();
    
    // Making the current slide outside the container:
    allSlides[currentSlide].style.transform = `translateX(${(currentSlide) * -100}%)`; 
    
     // Bring the next slide to the container:
     allSlides[currentSlide + 1].style.transform = `translateX(0%)`;
     ++currentSlide;
}

const setToInitialPosition = () => {
    allSlides.forEach((slide, index) => {
        // Reset all slides to their initial positions:
        slide.style.transform = `translateX(${index * 100}%)`;
    });

    // Reset the current slide index:
    currentSlide = 0;
};

slider();
```

you can find the full code here : https://codepen.io/Marya-ai/pen/ZEwRNRE

I would highly appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: Well I'd start by fixing the errors in the console...

Comment: @0stone0 Thanks for your reply, I'm aware of the error in the console that's why I've said "I don't know why it ignores the condition which checks `currentSlide`'s value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look into the console, then you will see that you have error(cannot read properties of undefined). So to fix this you should make

```js
if(currentSlide === 0 || currentSlide === numOfSlides-1) setToInitialPosition();
```

to avoid `length of array + 1` issue

But if you will make console log of your data (currentSlide) you can notice that your representation(numbers) doesn't satisfy data. To avoid confusion make your code reliable on data

Comment: thanks for replying. my first implementation was `const numOfSlides = allSlides.length -1 ;` but then I thought if the `currentSlide = 4`  which is the last slide then this would fulify the condition and go to `setToInitialPosition()` without showing the fourth slide. so I decided to leave it `const numOfSlides = allSlides.length ;` so when the `currentSlide` incremented to be 5 and comes back again to the condition `if(currentSlide === 0 || currentSlide === numOfSlides) setToInitialPosition();`, but now it turns out that I was wrong